# cake php list data and their related values to comma delemited id

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My database have category table that is related to more than one city. In the categories table the city column has comma separated id for example 1, 2, 3.
When I retrieve data from categories table i want that the city column contain the corresponding city names instead of city id.

```
$categoryDetails = $this->Category->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('slug'=> $slug)));

Array
(

[Category] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [parent_id] => 2
        [city] => 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
        [slug] => college
        [type] => 
        [lft] => 31
        [rght] => 32
        [name] => College
        [description] => College


        [image_name] => 1376938860_1185824_431052847008731_328184125_n.jpg
        [created] => 1376938860
        [modified] => 1376938860
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP is designed to handle model relationships, what you're doing is completely circumventing what Cake has been designed to do.  Furthermore, in general you do not want to link entries in separate tables by storing ids in a comma separated list.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

If a city will only ever belong to one category, use a hasMany relationship.  If a city can belong to many categories, use a HABTM relationship.

I'm guessing what you probably want is a HABTM relationship.  Drop the city field from the categories table, and make an additional categories_cities table that has the fields category_id and city_id.  For the example you gave, it should look like this:

```
 category_id  |  city_id
 10           |  2
 10           |  3
 10           |  4
 10           |  5
 10           |  6
 10           |  7
 10           |  8
 10           |  9
 10           |  10
```

Then add to your Category model the following:

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'City' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'joinTable' => 'categories_cities',
            'foreignKey' => 'city_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id',
            'unique' => true,
        )
);
```

Once you've set up the relationship, Cake will naturally fetch the cities you've related to the category when you do a find for that category, assuming the model's recursive property is set to 0 or higher.  (Defaultly, it's set to 1.)  Alternatively, you can use the containable behavior.

Comment: Thankyou Kai for the solution, its fine and it will definitely work fine. But the problem is that I have many more data that is related to cities like this, Like Offers, Events, Services, Business etc. in this way the database will be too massive and I have to change the whole database, since the admin is ready to use only front I have to work. Please give any other idea if possible.

Comment: Changing the database shouldn't make it that much larger larger.  And it should also be fairly easy to write scripts to convert your existing data over to the different schema.  This way you have it now, it makes your database prone to problems unless you are very, very careful to maintain integrity, like if you ever deleted a city, you would have to go through all categories and make sure they aren't in the city field anymore.  If you really must keep it this way, you will have to do a manual find for each city in the field.  But I really do not recommend it.